# Storage Permission Issue In android 10+ devices

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

i am trying to create a video player ,So I am trying to add the videos to the list
Storage permission is required to fetch the videos, so I took the permission with the below code.
But playstore was reject My app for this **MANAGE EXTERNAL STORAGE** permission.
But without this permission, I can't get storage permission on Android 10+ device.
To change the name of the video, delete the video and download the video permission is required , so please help me , please tell me how to get storage permission (/storage/Media/Videos , /storage/Download/)

**My storage permission code :-**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
     android:maxSdkVersion="28" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**Main activity code :-**

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
    } else {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionActivity.this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(PermissionActivity.this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}


private void requestPermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        try {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(String.format("package:%s",getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2296);
        }
    } else {
        //below android 11
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(PermissionActivity.this, new String[]{WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 2296) {
        if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                // perform action when allow permission success
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                boolean READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                boolean WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if (READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE && WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
                    // perform action when allow permission success
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Allow permission for storage access!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

So please tell me how to take storage permission in Android10+ Devices and also below Android 10 devices with out using MANAGE EXTERNAL STORAGE permission , Please Help Me

Comment: `(/storage/Media/Videos , /storage/Download/)` Those are non existing, impossible paths. Where did you get them from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions have changed in Android 10+:

> **External storage access scoped to app files and media**
>
> By default, apps targeting Android 10 and higher are given scoped access into external storage, or scoped storage. Such apps can see the following types of files within an external storage device without needing to request any storage-related user permissions [..]

Source: [Privacy changes in Android 10](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage)

> On devices that run Android 10 or higher, you don't need any storage-related permissions to access and modify media files that your app owns, including files in the `MediaStore.Downloads` collection

Source: [Storage Permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#storage-permission)

Comment: sir thats mean permission is not rquired

Comment: Yes, kind of, depending on what you need to do. Accessing the file system got a bit easier :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

in application tag in manifest file then you are done for an Android Q/10 device.

It will behave as it behaved on before 10.

I do not understand why you would have any problem on Android 10.

On Android 11+ you should be able to see media files in the usual public directories.